# Strongly typed data control throws compilation error: The name 'Item' does not exist

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid

In Visual Studio 2015 I'm trying to use a strongly typed RadGrid as described in [ASP.NET](https://www.asp.net/whitepapers/whats-new-in-aspnet-45-and-visual-studio-2012#_Toc318097385) and [Telerik](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-binding/model-binding-and-strongly-typed-data-controls-support) documentation, but with no success.

When I try to run the following page I get a compilation error:

```
CS0103: The name 'Item' does not exist in the current context
```

**WebForm1.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebAppNamespace.WebForm1" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>

<telerik:RadGrid runat="server"
    ItemType="ModelNamespace.SomeEntity"
    SelectMethod="GetTheStuff"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <MasterTableView>
        <Columns>

            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Item.SomeProperty%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

**WebForm1.aspx.cs**

```
using ModelNamespace;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace WebAppNamespace
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : Page
    {
        SomeContext db = new SomeContext();
        public IQueryable<SomeEntity> GetTheStuff()
        {
            return db.SomeEntity;
        }
    }
}
```

The code completion in Visual Studio doesn't work either.

Shoudn't `Item` be available when I use the `ItemType` attribute in the RadGrid control as described in the documentation? What am I missing?

Comment: Are you try "<%# Eval("SomeProperty")%>"?

Comment: Yes, I have tryed it and it works.I'm trying to avoid it since it seems quite slow.

Comment: Are you try also add DataField and HeaderText property to GridTemplateColumn?? And with these properties use <%# Item.SomeProperty %>

Comment: See http://www.telerik.com/forums/access-to-values-of-gridtemplatecolumn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `Item` object to be available in bind expressions, the `ItemType` property has to be specified on the `MasterTableView` element, i.e.:

```
<telerik:RadGrid runat="server"
    SelectMethod="GetTheStuff"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <MasterTableView ItemType="ModelNamespace.SomeEntity">
        <Columns>
        ...
```